# Regex to extract file paths except urls

Tags: python, regex

I have a large text containing some file paths, and I need a regex which can help me extract all the paths. Currently I'm using this one:

```
\/.+?\/[\w]+\.\w+
```

It works almost perfectly, but links containing filename or a dot at the end are interpreted as paths too, like this one:

```
http://example.com/index.html
```

Help in providing a valid regular expression is highly appreciated. Also if you can add support of spaces in paths in this regex, it would be awesome. Thanks in advance!

Link to regex test: [click](https://pythex.org/?regex=%5C%2F.%2B%3F%5C%2F%5B%5Cw%5D%2B%5C.%5Cw%2B&test_string=%2Fabc%2Fdef%2Fdef.ps%0A%20http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Findex.html&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this one is not working properly

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Well, results are the same as while using regex I provided. "//example.com/index.html" is extracted, but it shouldn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a negative look-behind to exclude the "http:" and "https:" prefix.

```
(?<!https:)(?<!http:)(?<!/)(?<!\w)((/[^\s]+)?/\w+\.\w+)
```

If you try it with this test strings in pythex:

```
/abc/def/def.ps
/abc/def/ttt/def.ps
/test.txt
/abc/test.txt http://example.com/index.html
 http://www.google.com/bla/test/index.html https://www.google.com/bla/test/index.html
```

It will only match the first 4.

Here is the [pythex](https://pythex.org/?regex=(%3F%3C!https%3A)(%3F%3C!http%3A)(%3F%3C!%2F)(%3F%3C!%5Cw)((%2F%5B%5E%5Cs%5D%2B)%3F%2F%5Cw%2B%5C.%5Cw%2B)&test_string=%2Fabc%2Fdef%2Fdef.ps%0A%2Fabc%2Fdef%2Fttt%2Fdef.ps%0A%2Ftest.txt%0A%2Fabc%2Ftest.txt%20http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Findex.html%0A%20http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fbla%2Ftest%2Findex.html%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fbla%2Ftest%2Findex.html&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0) link.

The advantage of this regular expression is that is does not rely on the beginning of the line to work.

You can add as many look behinds as you wish to support other protocols, like ftp, etc.

Comment: Any comments on this approach?

Comment: Thanks, it works almost perfectly, except http/https support

Comment: Just added support for https. You could add more look behinds in order to support other protocols. Please check the updated answer and let me know your thinking about this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this : `^\/.+?\/[\w]+\.\w+$` with multi-line mode enabled.